# How to display separate paragraphs in the same area using CSS HTML

Tags: css, html, button, slidetoggle

I'm in the process of making a simple webpage, and have run into a wall. Right now, I have a few buttons laid out on the page with the slideToggle animation, and when you click one, a paragraph opens directly under the button. My question is, how can I get all of these separate paragraphs to appear in the same spot? I want them to all appear at the bottom of the page, so that when you click a button, none of the other buttons jump around awkwardly on the page. Here's my HTML:

```
<h2>Click to learn more about me!</h2>
    <div class="trait">
        <button>Trait1</button>
    </div>
    <p class="note">Blah</p>

    <div class="trait">
        <button>Trait2</button>
    </div>
    <p class="note">BlahBlah</p>

    <div class="trait">
        <button>Trait3</button>
    </div>
    <p class="note">BlahBlahBlah</p>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}

div p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 450px;
}

button {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

.note {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want them to appear in the same place have you tired putting all of the paragraphs in the same place in your mark-up?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vUyTH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `position: absolute;` instead of `relative`, and set a `left` property. For example:

```
.note {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This will cause all `.note` paragraphs to overlap each other in the bottom left corner of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have another div like `<div id="paragraphInfo"></div>` Place it where you want and then use jQuery to take take the paragraph info and show it in the new div.

You could fix up the slideToggle to show and hide when you want but his is just to give you an idea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#paragraphInfo, p').hide();

      $('button').click(function(){
            $('#paragraphInfo').hide();
            pText = $(this).parent().next('.note').html();
            $('#paragraphInfo').html(pText);

            $('#paragraphInfo').slideToggle();
      });

});
```

**UPDATE**

Added the paragraph hide once button is clicked so it should slide toggle correctly now.